# How to orbit in Blender without a MMB these days?

Tags: blender

In Windows I use Alt + LMB
Unfortunately this combination seems to conflict with something in Ubuntu, as it does change the cursor into a grabbing hand but does not orbit.
I thought of using the Super key instead, but it's bound to the Unity Launcher shortcuts 
I know you can use strictly the keyboard, but it's not quite the same 
Btw, I don't have a MMB. Reason why I use the Alt key in Windows.

Any ideas?

JDL

Answer (score 2):

[Unity Tweak Tool setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDp0U.png)
Thanks to the Unity Tweak Tool, you can disable the Super key from bringing up the HUD shortcuts when hold down.
Once that's done, in the Blender Prefs, under Input/3D view/3D View (Global)/Rotate View, set it to use Super + LMB.
Note that the Super key shows as "Cmd" in Blender.

Similarly do this to select loops in Edit mode:
[Blender Prefs setup for "select loops" screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VygN.png)

Comment: It is a great way. However, if you happen to use it a lot, then I do not suggest that. | I use Super key a lot, especially as shortcuts, changing workspaces, searching through applications/files.